# Does still make sense to use SHA1?

Tags: hash, sha-1, hash-signature, embedded

I'm working with Arduino and [hash-based signatures](http://www.pqsignatures.org/) which are signature schemes that use only hash functions. Due to the constraints of an Arduino I was thinking about using SHA1 as the underlying function of my hash-based signature. But I'm not sure if it still makes sense to use SHA1 due to its vulnerabilities. Is there a scenario in which would be acceptable to use SHA1?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the specific scheme but e.g. in [this paper](https://huelsing.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/wotsspr.pdf) the security proof relies on second preimage resistance, for which SHA1 would still be fine.

Comment: Note however, that you would need to avoid pre-hashing with SHA-1 which may or may not be tricky.

Comment: fwiw, sha256 runs faster on ardunio than sha1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, use SHA256.**

If you look at https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-hash.html it seems that SHA256 would probably be the better choice concerning speed as well. Therefore I don't see a good reason to go with SHA-1.